# Printing number pattern using python

Tags: python

Does any one know how to print this pattern using python?

0000000001
0000000002
0000000003
0000000004
0000000005
0000000006
0000000007
0000000008
0000000009
0000000010
0000000011

I am a beginner here..Pls help..

Comment: Beginner or not...c'mon.  Could you please make some effort towards solving it?  How would you approach it on paper?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `zfill(n)` function of **str class** to fill zeros on the left of the string to make it of some **length n**.

```
>>> for i in range(1,15):
...    print str(i).zfill(10),
... 
0000000001 0000000002 0000000003 0000000004 0000000005 0000000006 0000000007 0000000008 0000000009 0000000010 0000000011 0000000012 0000000013 0000000014
```

Answer (score 2):

you can also use rjust:

```
>>> for x in range(20):
...     print str(x).rjust(10,'0'),
... 
0000000000 0000000001 0000000002 0000000003 0000000004 0000000005 0000000006 0000000007 0000000008 0000000009 0000000010 0000000011 0000000012 0000000013 0000000014 0000000015 0000000016 0000000017 0000000018 0000000019
```

using format:

```
>>> for x in range(20):
...     print "{:0>10}".format(x),
... 
0000000000 0000000001 0000000002 0000000003 0000000004 0000000005 0000000006 0000000007 0000000008 0000000009 0000000010 0000000011 0000000012 0000000013 0000000014 0000000015 0000000016 0000000017 0000000018 0000000019
```